# C Segmentation Fault (core dumped) Linked List

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, void-pointers, coredump

I keep getting `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)` run time error and I can't figure out why.

My code:

```
struct Node
{
    void *next;
    void *val;
};
typedef struct Node* NodePtr;

struct List
{
    NodePtr head;
};
typedef struct List* ListPtr;

ListPtr create()
{
    ListPtr ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct List));

    return ptr;
}

int insert(ListPtr list, void *obj)
{
    NodePtr newObj = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    //Cast next as a self referencing Node
    newObj->next = (NodePtr) newObj->next;

    //Point to beginning of list
    NodePtr current = list->head;

    if(list->head == NULL)
    {
        newObj->val = obj;
        list->head->next = newObj;
        newObj->next = NULL;

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = 2;
    int *p = &x;

    ListPtr thing = create();

    insert(thing, p);

    return 0;
}
```

The error is here:  `list->head->next = newObj` after some debugging. I thought I had to allocate memory for list->head->next, but when I added the code in for that it still gave me the same error. Am I casting it wrong or not allocating memory correctly? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `list->head->next = newObj;` if(list->head == NULL) ==> `NULL->next = newObj;`. also `list->head` isn't initialize.

Comment: Pro-tip: in your first year(s) of C, don't use typedef. It would only confuse you.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot initialize head. Added that in but still no luck. I also have to use typedef, assignment has typedef in it. My code I posted is not part of it but it's similar.

Comment: in the struct Node definition: `void *next;` is bad practice, it will suppress type checking, and thus strong typing. (you could, for instance do `struct Node *p= malloc(sizeof *p) ; p->next = "Hello, world\n";` , without any warning or error from the compiler.

Comment: You never initialize the list head.  You need to before you try and access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this together, runs fine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct Node {
        void *next;
        void *val;
};
typedef struct Node* NodePtr;

struct List {
    NodePtr head;
};
typedef struct List* ListPtr;

ListPtr CreateList() {
    ListPtr ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    return ptr;
}

void Insert(ListPtr list, void *obj) {
        // create and initialize new node
    NodePtr newObj = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newObj->val = obj;
    newObj->next = NULL;

    //Point to beginning of list
    NodePtr curr = list->head;
    // Add node to the list
    if(curr == NULL) // if no head node, make newObj the head node
    {
        list->head = newObj;
    }
    else{ // otherwise traverse the list until you find the last node (the one that points to a null as the next)
        while(1) {
                if(curr->next != NULL) {
                        curr = curr -> next;
                } else {
                        curr->next = newObj;
                }
                list->head = newObj;
                newObj->val = obj;
                list->head->next = newObj;
                newObj->next = NULL;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    int x = 2;
    int *p = &x;

    ListPtr thing = CreateList();

    Insert(thing, p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked and I finally understand everyone else too.

Answer (score 1):

You check if `list->head` is NULL and then do some operations with that. Change that to `if(list->head != NULL)
{
...
}`

Answer (score 1):

At a thought, malloc does not guarantee allocated memory is empty.  It's good practice to set all values where they matter after allocation.
list->head is probably not null

also :  newObj->next = (NodePtr) newObj->next;
doesn't set to a rational value, it sets to whatever memory was set - were you intending newObj->next = (NodePtr) newObj;  ?

list->head should not be referenced if null.  list->head->next will only be valid if it's not null.

if you actually want to build a list,

```
newObj->val = obj;
if (list->head == NULL) { newObj->next = list->head; }
list->head = newObj;
```

either that or travel down list->head->next chain until next is null, and set that to be newObj->next.  If that way then it's possibly a good idea, newObj->next should be set to NULL and not itself.

Might want to figure out how your list will behave - is it circular?  does it grow from the head (list->head) or tail (last ->next) ?    Do you spot the tail when listObject->next == NULL or when listObject->next == listObject ?

Comment: Are you saying I should use `memset()` after `mallo()`? In Java, when you make a singly-linked list, you have a self referential node. For example, `public class Node { Node link; int value; }`. This is why I did `newObj->next = (NodePtr) newObj->next`. I wanted next to be self referential like in Java. Also you're right, I was trying to do list->head->next == NULL. How would I make it self referential like in Java?

Comment: memset works.  On most platforms NULL=0.  (that's a gotcha too, but not usually terribly important).  

Self reference is newObj->next = newObj;  

But why self referenced?   Does that mean for (listIter=list->head; 
listiter!=listiter->next; listiter = listiter->next) is the style of iteration you want?  (where listiter is a NodePtr)

Comment: For self reference I mean I want `void *next` to be `NodePtr next`. However, I can't write that in the Node struct, so I tried to do it outside.

Comment: @Maru : there are three ways to avoid that: 1) `struct Node *next;` 2) a typedef on an incomplete type 0) don't use typedef (see my 1st comment)

Comment: Thanks! Learned something new. Although, I still need to use typedef outside of the struct because my professor wants us to use it.

Comment: `typedef struct Node* NodePtr;
struct Node {
        NodePtr next;
        void *val;
};`
Should work - that'd be (2) typedef on an incomplete type as per @wildplasser

Comment: @Maru : find another professor. Or ignore his advice after you finished school...

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this answer is mostly stylistic. But I do think that (bad) style and (bad) habits are an (important) part of (bad) programming. Summing it up ...

---

- (in most cases) typedefs are not needed; they just introduce an alias for something that already existed.
- [rule of seven] human readers have a limited amount of identifiers ("names") that they can keep track of. This could be 7. Minimising the number of distinct words makes reading easier.
- also, the reader has to remember that xPtr and xNode are *related* (typeof *xPtr === typeof xNode)
- when reading source code, keywords and special character tokens (such as operators) don't *count* as an identifier, since you do not have to remember them. (Syntax-highligting helps, too)
- if there is only one way of expressing your program, there is no possibility for errors like `iPtr *p; p = (qPtr) malloc (sizeof xNode);`
- creating yet another struct (+typedefs for it), just to accomodate a *root* pointer will clobber up your mental namespace even more.

Now a rework of the (intended) code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    struct node *next;
    void *payload;
    };

struct node *root=NULL;

void initialize() { /* nothing .... */ }

int insert(struct node **pp, void *pv) {
   struct node *p;

   p = malloc(sizeof *p);
   if (!p) { /* handle error */ return -1; }

   p->payload = pv;
   p->next = *pp;
   *pp = p;
   return 1; /* inserted one element */
 }

int main(void)
{
int i;

i=666;

 /* note: this function call will pass a pointer to a local variable `i`
 ** to the insert() function, which will remember it.
 ** This is generally a bad idea, to say the least.
 */
insert( &root, &i);

return 0;
}
```